# Flash AS3 making a mask with movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mask, movieclip, masking

I want to apply mask effect into movie clip.

I made a movie clip that was divided 3 areas.

```
parent movie clip name is "box"

1 area name(Child box) = "m0" as MovieClip
2 area name(Child box) = "m1" as MovieClip
3 area name(Child box) = "m2" as MovieClip
```

I've converted image file to movie clip named "pic.."

```
1 photo file(Located at Stage) = "pic0" as MovieClip
2 photo file(Located at Stage) = "pic1" as MovieClip
3 photo file(Located at Stage) = "pic2" as MovieClip
```

I'd like to apply masking effect dynamically.

I have no idea of this,
Can you give an advice a little bit?

```
var btn:MovieClip = this["btn"] as MovieClip;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goon);

function goon(Event:MouseEvent):void{
    var pic0:MovieClip = this["pic0"] as MovieClip;
    var pic1:MovieClip = this["pic1"] as MovieClip;
    var pic2:MovieClip = this["pic2"] as MovieClip;
    var box:MovieClip = this["box"] as MovieClip;
    trace(box.m0.x + " , " + box.m0.y);

    //box.addChild(mc0);
    box["m0"].mask = box["m0"];
    box["m0"].addChild(pic0);
    pic0.x = 0;
    pic0.y = 0;

}
```

However it's not working at all.
And I'm wondering do I need add child methods in my code?
What should i do?

Comment: you need to be much more clear in what you want. Can you add some images?

Comment: No, there are 3 images in the stage. I'd like to know how to adjust mask effect with one movie clip.

Comment: What I meant is can you add some images into your question here to explain what you're trying to do. It's hard to tell. For example, I can't tell what you want to use as the mask and what thing you want to mask.

Comment: @Richard Try this for example : `pic0.mask = box.m0; pic1.mask = box.m1; pic2.mask = box.m2;` ...

Comment: @akmozo That's how you do it :) Thank you very much~

Comment: @Jezzamon I got it. I'll do better next time. Thank you